# How To Create A CheckBoxList in Maya

Tags: list, checkboxlist, maya, mel

i want to create a checkbox list in Autodesk Maya (MEL only) which contains N number of items along with a check/ uncheck option next to it. so that on click of a button i can get value of all checked or unchecked items. There is a component called textscrolllist but it does not support checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Controls" category in the MEL reference, you will find the `checkBox` and `checkBoxGroup` commands. You can query the state with the `-value` or `-valueN` flags.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but i want to generate the list dynamically and it should be scrollable (same as they have reference list in Maya > File > reference editor or checklistbox in delphi). But here in maya if i use checkBox or checkBoxGroup and in case the item goes beyond assigned window size then i am not able to scroll it accordingly.

Comment: You could put the checkboxes in a `scrollLayout`, and simply destroy and recreate the window if you add or remove checkboxes. Or you could check out how they do the reference editor, it should be in scripts/other/referenceEditorPanel.mel. Note that you can find out a lot about how they do things in the UI with the `whatIs` command.

Comment: unfortunately i have already gon through with all related MEL procedures in scripts/other dir along with referenceEditorPanel. what i got is they have a separate control called sceneEditor which displays the reference list and carries other reference related info. so i think i can't use that as a component and thanks for the scroll Layout will definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site. This has helped me over the past few years when it comes to creating custom UIs in mel. Below is some block text on how to create a checkbox within a UI.

https://nccastaff.bournemouth.ac.uk/jmacey/RobTheBloke/www/mel/GUI_controls.html

```
// a function to be called when the checkbox gets checked.
proc on_func() {
    print("checkbox on!\n");
}

// a function to be called when the checkbox gets unchecked.
proc off_func() {
    print("checkbox on!\n");
}

{
    // create a window
    window;

        // define the layout of controls added 
        // to the window.
        columnLayout;

            // create a checkbox
            $c = `checkBox -label "thingy" 
                     -onCommand "on_func" 
                     -offCommand "off_func"`;

    // show the window we last created
    showWindow;


    // to get the current value of the checkBox, use the -query flag
    $value = `checkBox -query -value $c`;

    print("check_box value = "+ $value +"\n");
}
```